# Visual Basic List Updating Other Elements When Adding

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list in Visual Basic to add an athlete.  If the list is empty, the item adds correctly.  However if I want to add another item, it does but it replaces the others items with the newly added item.

From a Add Athlete form I call this:

```
Club.AddAthlete(New Athlete(TextBoxName.Text, TextBoxEmail.Text,
        TextBoxNumber.Text, DateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString()))
```

Then in the class Club, I have a list made up of Athletes:

```
Public Class Club
    Public Shared athletes As New List(Of Athlete)()

    Public Shared Sub AddAthlete(ByVal r As Athlete)
        athletes.Add(r)
    End Sub
```

For example I call Add with the information ("name1", "email1", "number1", 25/01/15) and this adds correctly as it is the first item

Then I call Add again with this information ("name2", "email2", "number2", 24/01/15) and this adds but it changes the data of the first item to this data

If anyone could help with this, I would be very grateful,

---

```
Public Class Athlete 
    Shared Name As String = "" 
    Shared Email As String = "" 
    Shared Number As String = "" 
    Shared DoB As String = "" 
    Sub New(InName As String, InEmail As String, 
              InNumber As String, InDoB As String) 
        Name = InName 
        Email = InEmail 
        Number = InNumber 
        DoB = InDoB 
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you show the Sub New for Athlete?  Why is everything in Club Shared?  As an aside, you might be better off storing the date as a DateTime type rather than converting to string.

Comment: I *cannot* reproduce this behavior. You need to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Public Class Athlete
    Shared Name As String = ""
    Shared Email As String = ""
    Shared Number As String = ""
    Shared DoB As String = ""

    Sub New(InName As String, InEmail As String, InNumber As String, InDoB As String)
        Name = InName
        Email = InEmail
        Number = InNumber
        DoB = InDoB
    End Sub

I have used the date as a string, because I only want to view it once added, and using a string or datetime should make no difference to this

Comment: I have put the code here:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4b1a

Comment: @JoeMurray The problem is that you have declared the fields (Name, Email, etc.) of the Athlete class as Shared. That means there is only one value for those fields that is shared by all the Athlete objects. That isn;t what you want. Declare them as Public (or Private if you are going to provide a provide properties to access them) and remove the Shared modifier.

Comment: dont post long code snippets in comments; they do not format. you can always edit your post to add more info,  But, yes get rid of all the `Shared` modifiers

Comment: Apologies for that.  However, thank you very much for this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Only a few of those functions should have a Shared modifier, the rest are supposed to use data that is different for each instance of the class, and should not be Shared. You can also simplify your code by replacing the GetXXXX and SetXXXX functions with a property (if you don't want to allow Set, make it a ReadOnly Property). Here is an example.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Athlete
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Number As String
    Public Property DoB As String

    Sub New(InName As String, InEmail As String, InNumber As String, InDoB As String)
        Name = InName
        Email = InEmail
        Number = InNumber
        DoB = InDoB
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

    Public Sub Save(textOut As TextWriter)
        textOut.WriteLine(Name)
        textOut.WriteLine(Email)
        textOut.WriteLine(Number)
        textOut.WriteLine(DoB)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(textIn As TextReader) As Athlete
        Dim name As String = textIn.ReadLine()
        Dim email As String = textIn.ReadLine()
        Dim number As String = textIn.ReadLine()
        Dim dob As String = textIn.ReadLine()
        Return New Athlete(name, email, number, dob)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Club
    Public Property ClubName As String
    Public Property Athletes As New List(Of Athlete)()

    Public Sub New(inClubName As String)
        ClubName = inClubName
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveText(textOut As TextWriter)
        textOut.WriteLine(ClubName)
        textOut.WriteLine(Athletes.Count)
        For Each ath As Athlete In Athletes
             ath.Save(textOut)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Save()
        Using textOut As New StreamWriter("runnersData.txt")
            SaveText(textOut)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(textIn As TextReader) As Club
        Dim myClub As New Club(textIn.ReadLine())
        Dim noOfRunners As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(textIn.ReadLine(), noOfRunners)
        For i As Integer = 0 To noOfRunners - 1
            myClub.Athletes.Add(Athlete.Load(textIn))
        Next
    Return myClub
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Load() As Club
        Return Load(New StreamReader("runnersData.txt"))
    End Function
End Class
```